# installing nodejs via the downloaded file from website in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, react-native, ubuntu

I have downloaded the nodejs repository from nodejs website and I want to install it via node file in bin directory and I want to install it with gdebi or software installer app but the error is:[image: for gdebi] for gdebi and [image: for software installer] for software installer actually I have checked the permissions and activated them and this is the error while I run `npx create-react-app name`

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ini'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just some extra packages remaining from past which I could handle with `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean` then I reinstalled nodejs via terminal